# AddEventListener running twice

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I'm writing a simply game in javascript, which consists of colored squares and you have to choose the square with the rgb displayed in the screen.
What happens is that when I click in a square, and then I click play again to get a new color, addEventListener runs twice, the first time it says that the answer is equals the previous rgb value, the second time it says the answer is equals the new rgb value. The problem is that entering with the wrong answer, makes you points = 0 even though you got it right.
Any suggests what might be happening?

That's my code:

```
   window.onload = function() {
    var buttonNewColor = document.getElementById("buttonNewColor");
    var squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");
    
    buttonNewColor.onclick = getColors;
  }
```

```
   function getColors() {
    answer = colors[getRandomInt(6) - 1];
    colorChoice.innerHTML = answer;
    console.log("answer top: " + answer);

    for (var i = 0; i < squares.length; i ++) {
        squares[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
    
        squares[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
            console.log("Square Clicked");

            clickedColor = this.style.backgroundColor;
            
            console.log("clickedColor: " + clickedColor);
            console.log("answer: " + answer);

            if (clickedColor === answer) {
                console.log("points: " + points);
                message.textContent = "Correct";
                buttonNewColor.textContent = "Play Again";
                points = points + 1;
                score.innerHTML = "Score: " + points;
                changeColors(answer);
                answer = " ";
            } else {
                console.log("Entering on else")
                points = 0;
                score.textContent = "Score: " + points; 
                message.textContent = "Try Again";
            }

           

        });
     }
  }
```

Comment: More context is needed, the provided example doesn't add multiple event listeners to the same element.

Comment: Where does `squares` come from?

Comment: @CapitanFindus  I'm using squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square"), and all my squares have the class square.

Comment: Can you put the code in Codepen or some other online editor?

Comment: @AleksGrunwald https://codepen.io/cedoispirdb/pen/poRBqxW